# Nautilus preferences and menu missing

Tags: 11.04, unity, nautilus

My nautilus does not show a preferences button or file/edit etc when I hove over the left top. I recently did a clean install of Ubuntu natty narwhal 11.04. What happened and how can I fix this?
See screnshot here

[image]

Comment: Are you not missing the global menu on the top of the screen (hover your mouse over the bar at the top)? Or Is the top bar gone completely?

Comment: Vote to close, as there is no feedback to above question.

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal and type `sudo apt-get install nautilus`.

Then restart your session.

For some reason, Nautilus is not completely updated when you install the Elementary version. This will complete the upgrading process and Preferences and Menu will be there again the next time you start Nautilus.

Answer (score -3):

1. Install compiz fusion icon from synaptic
2. In compiz fusion icon choose for "select windows manager' and then for Metacity.
3. If you have your preferences and menu back then compiz is the reason why.

Comment: Too bad, that didn't solve it. I changed into classic ubuntu interface and now nautilus looks okay again; too bad for unity!